# Selecting Multiple Cells (SQL, WinForms)

Tags: sql, windows-forms-designer

Good afternoon! I have a problem:

I need to select a pair of cells from one database table (which I know how to do), and after that I need to put all the cells from another database that satisfy the condition in the same row.

For example, I need columns "1", "2" and "3" from table "A", and all cells of column "3" from table "B", where [B].[2] == [A].[1] in one row.

But alas, it only turns out that I have a huge number of rows, where there is only one cell from column [B].[3]. I couldn't find anything on the forums / documentation, alas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.39c6508c-62b1a4ec-5805a3e8-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/46799466/how-to-select-multiple-fields-from-a-single-column-and-output-to-a-single-row). I just had to search the Internet a little more. ^^

Comment: Try to avoid posting link-only answers, as those links may change or be abandoned over time. Review [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips